# First click on TableRow - very slow response

Tags: android, performance, tablelayout, tablerow

I have this strange issue and can't figure it out. I have a `TableLayout` with `TableRow's`, which have `onClickListener`. I want to highlight tableRow when clicked ... everything seems fine except very slow response when first time clicked. 
When i click TableRow, it takes about 8 seconds to highlight TableRow, but it is taking long just first time. When i click to other row and then back to row that was previously highlighted, response is "instantly". I should mention that table containes 30rows and 13 columns. Response time decreases when limiting to few rows and columns.

Why does it take so much time on first click, and not on second click?

This is my `onClick` method:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{       
    if (v instanceof TableRow){
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();            
        TableRow row = (TableRow) v;
        if (selectedRow != null){
            selectedRow.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);              
        }
        row.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.selected_row));          
        selectedRow = row;          
        long estimatedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        Log.v(TEST_TAG, "Time elapsed when clicked:" + estimatedTime);      
    }       
}
```

It spends few miliseconds in OnClick method, and few seconds to draw background color to display.

Comment: Without showing what you do in that `OnClickListener` nobody can really help you.

Comment: @Luksprog ... i updated my answer. It realy has to be something with onDraw or something similar that i don't understand yet. It behaves like on second click, whole view comes from some kind of cache...

Comment: have You tried to do http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html for this function?

Comment: @sandrstar i'll give it a try. I'm new to Android development ... so thank you for that tip.

Comment: Is it a simple listview? Try enable debug overdrawn http://www.curious-creature.org/docs/android-performance-case-study-1.html

Comment: @LeonArmstrong it is a TableLayout. I'm developing component for 2.2 android and overdrawn is for at least 4.2. I've tried it but can't get it work.

Comment: I'm creating this table dynamically, and width of views inside tableRows are set to WRAP_CONTENT. I thought this coud be an issue so i created fixed layout in XML with 30 rows and 13 columns for testing to see if there is any difference in performance.

Comment: I found out that this way, performance is a slightly better, but it still is too bad. 
I decided to change TableLayout with ListView because of many performance issues with TableLayout. I guess it is not good to use TableLayout with more than dozen of View's inside it which is a bit shame.
I hope i will be able to implement all functionalities of table with LinearView. :S

Comment: Actually, that's the ListView created for - handle scrollable screens with many items in an efficient way.